# how convert classes of element to an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i have a `<div>` like this.

```
<div id="div" class="a b _c d _e f"></div>
```

how can convert classes of `<div>` to a javaScript array?

```
var cls = $('#div').attr('class');
cls = $(cls).match(/_\S+/g).join(" "); //separate classes are begin with underScore.
cls = $(cls).toArray();
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: what is the desired output

Comment: `$(cls).match` is wrong because `.match()` is defined for `String` type, so it should be `cls = cls.match(/_\S+/g)`

Comment: What is it with your nickname?

Comment: @Arun P Johny i want when other `<div>` has classes that begin with underScore, A condition run.

Comment: console.log(cls.replace(/_/gi,'').split(' ')); or use just split() to have array.

Comment: still not clear, can you prepare a fiddle like this http://jsfiddle.net/j2m3N/2/ with the desired markup and output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `split()` function:

```
var array;
array = $('#div').attr('class').split(' ');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var classes = $("#div").attr("class").split(" ");
```

Comment: damn you! :D easiest and obviously solution.
After that you simply can iterate over the array and exlucde all classes without the underscore

Comment: Is this code correct? : `var classes = $("#div").attr('class').match(/_\S+/g).split(' ')`

Comment: No, becouse `"".match()` returns array. You can't split array.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it in plain js:

```
document.getElementById('div').classList;
```

will give you the list of classes

Answer (score 0):

if($('#div').hasClass('old_class')){

$('#div').removeClass('old_class').addClass('new_Class');

}else{

$('#div').removeClass('new_class').addClass('old_Class');

}